# Проверка сочинения на наличие запятых, грамматических и речевых ошибок

Tags: пунктуация, грамотная-речь, грамматика, редактура

Доброго времени суток, дорогие телезрители. В эфире передача «Времена года» с Еленой Ишутиной. Посмотрите за окно, наступила весна. Отрещали морозы, отвыли вьюги и вот  еле- еле заметные шаги делает весна. 
 Все это напоминает мне картину замечательного художника К. Юона  «Конец зимы. Полдень». Природа пробуждается от долгого сна.  Вдалеке  отчетливо виднеется лес. Он вырос клочками, меж которых лежит серовато - розовый снег. Мальчишки, вставшие вдоль забора, радуются последним зимним денькам. О приближении весны говорит подтаявший и осевший   вокруг поленницы дров и на крыше дома снег.   Куры уже не прячутся от холода в курятник, а деловито прохаживаются по двору, отыскивая что-нибудь съестное. Стройные березки  бросают длинные голубые тени, этим автор показывает ослепительно - яркое солнце.
 Совсем скоро весна придет и к нам на улицы. А  сегодня на этом  все, включайте нашу телепрограмму в это же время в следующее воскресенье. До новых встреч.

Comment: Если вам дан хороший ответ, пожалуйста, не забудьте отметить его галочкой.

Answer (score 2):

**Вариант 1. Исправление ошибок**

Доброго времени суток, дорогие телезрители. В эфире передача «Времена года» с Еленой Ишутиной.

Посмотрите за окно, наступила **весна**. **Оттрещали** морозы, отвыли вьюги, и вот еле-еле заметные шаги делает **весна**. Все это напоминает мне картину замечательного художника К. Юона «Конец зимы. Полдень».

Природа пробуждается от долгого сна. Вдалеке отчетливо виднеется лес. **Он вырос клочками, между которыми** лежит серовато - розовый снег. **Мальчишки,** вставшие вдоль забора, радуются последним зимним денькам. О приближении весны говорит подтаявший и осевший вокруг поленницы дров и на крыше дома снег. **Куры** уже не прячутся от холода **в курятник**, а деловито прохаживаются по двору, отыскивая что-нибудь съестное.

Стройные березки бросают длинные голубые тени, **этим** автор показывает ослепительно - яркое солнце. Совсем скоро весна придет и к нам на улицы.

А сегодня на этом все, включайте нашу телепрограмму в это же время в следующее воскресенье. До новых встреч.

**Вариант 2. Редактирование**

Доброго времени суток, дорогие телезрители. В эфире передача «Времена года» с Еленой Ишутиной.

Посмотрите в окно, и вы увидите, как меняется  мир природы. Оттрещали морозы, отвыли вьюги, и уже первые, хотя и еле заметные шаги делает весна. Все это напоминает мне картину замечательного художника К. Юона «Конец зимы. Полдень».

Природа пробуждается от долгого сна. Вдалеке  виднеется лес, но на картине его закрывают пятна серовато-розового, солнечного, по-весеннему праздничного снега. Он лежит не крышах домов,  на еловых и березовых ветках.

Мороз легкий, погода прекрасная, и еще можно покататься на лыжах в последние  зимние деньки.  Вот и куры уже не прячутся от холода, а деловито прохаживаются по двору, отыскивая что-нибудь съестное.

От стройных березок на первом плане легли длинные голубые тени, так автор показывает ослепительно-яркое солнце. Совсем скоро весна придет и к нам на улицы.

А сегодня на этом всё, включайте нашу телепрограмму в это же время в следующее воскресенье. До новых встреч.

Answer (score 1):

Совсем неплохо для 7-го класса! Но ошибки есть.

> Доброго времени суток

Это не ошибка, но о неуместности такого обращения немало писали, в том числе и на нашем сайте. Лучше явно назвать время суток (утро, день, вечер) или просто поздороваться.

> Посмотрите за окно, наступила весна

Это не ошибка, но лучше использовать тире или двоеточие. *Посмотрите за окно — наступила весна.* (Если посмотрите за окно, то увидите, что наступила весна.)
*Посмотрите за окно: наступила весна.* (Посмотрите за окно и вот что там увидите: наступила весна.)

> Отрещали

Ошибка. Корректно: Оттрещали.

> ОтТрещали морозы, отвыли вьюги и вот еле- еле заметные шаги делает весна.

Ошибка. Необходим знак препинания между вторым и третьим предложением в составе ССП. Можно поставить запятую, но я бы предпочел тире, подчеркивая то, что третье является результатом первого и второго, следует за ними.

> Природа пробуждается от долгого сна...

Не ошибка, но я бы пояснил, что это началось описание картины.

> еле- еле, серовато - розовый,

Ошибка. Лишние пробелы. Корректно: еле-еле, серовато-розовый

> ослепительно - яркое

Дефис тут спорный. Розенталь рекомендует писать "ослепительно голубое небо" без дефиса. Но если дефис, то без пробелов.

> вставшие

Почему они встали? Лучше: стоящие.

Дополнение.

> Посмотрите за окно, наступила весна. Оттрещали морозы, отвыли вьюги, и вот еле-еле заметные шаги делает весна.

Логическое противоречие: весна уже наступила, но еще делает еле-еле заметные шаги.

> Мальчишки, вставшие вдоль забора, радуются последним зимним денькам.

Изображение описано неточно. На картине мальчишки на лыжах готовы отправиться на прогулку.

> радуются последним зимним денькам.

Не берусь судить, какие эмоции передают удаленные фигурки лыжников, но то, что они радуются **зимним** денькам, как-то плохо сочетается с общим тоном сочинения, которое посвящено приходу **весны**. Возможное исправление: радуются теплу последних зимних деньков.

> Стройные березки бросают длинные голубые тени, этим автор показывает ослепительно - яркое солнце

Меня смущает слово *показывает* по отношению к тому, что не изображено на картине.
Возможное исправление: Стройные березки бросают **четкие** длинные  тени, этим автор передает ощущение яркого солнца. (На мой взгляд, ослепительность солнечных лучей передана в первую очередь через то, как блестит на картине снег, как сияют все освещенные солнцем предметы.)

Comment: А Вы картину видели? По-моему, там лыжники, а не мальчишки у забора  чему-то радуются. И повторов много, фактические неточности:  куры в курятнике, весна то наступила, то делает еле заметные шаги. А как правильно: посмотреть в окно или за окно?

Comment: @Jasmin Нет, картину не видел, поверил на слово... А зря.

Comment: В Нацкопусе 26 вхождений "смотреть за окно"

Comment: Частотность  "в окно" значительно выше (мы обычно смотрим в окно), но "за окно" тоже встречается. За окно - это, наверное, взгляд за пределы окна, обзор всего пространства, а не просто посмотреть, не идет ли дождь.