# Ослепительно яркий или ослепительно-яркий?

Tags: прилагательные, наречия, раздельно-дефис

Розенталь рекомендует писать "ослепительно голубое небо" без дефиса. Думаю, тот же подход можно применить и к *ослепительно яркому*:

> 17. Следует различать сложные прилагательные (со слитным или дефисным написанием) и словосочетания, состоящие из наречия на -о/-е и прилагательного или причастия ([§ 39. Сложные прилагательные](http://old-rozental.ru/orfograf_uk.php?oid=2544.))

В Нацкорпусе мне удалось найти только написание без дефиса (*ослепительно яркий*).

В "[Орфографическом словаре-справочнике](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/rus_orthography/58524/%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE_%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9)": *ослепительно яркий* (без дефиса).
И в "[Словаре русской идиоматики](https://idiomatika.academic.ru/4269/%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE)" — *ослепительно яркий* (без дефиса).

Но в ["Орфографическом словаре"](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic?word=%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9) на Грамоте находим: *ослепительно-яркий*. 
И в словаре "[Слитно или раздельно?](http://sbiblio.com/biblio/content.aspx?dictid=141&letterid=62&pid=13)" — *ослепительно-яркий*.
В словаре "[Слитно. Раздельно. Через дефис](https://orthography.academic.ru/21850/%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE)." — *ослепительно-яркий*.

Сомнения возникли в связи с просьбой проверить сочинение ([Проверка сочинения на наличие запятых, грамматических и речевых ошибок](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/440171/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BA/440178#440178)).

Думаю, правило о дефисном написании оттенков цветов здесь неприменимо, так как ослепительность не есть оттенок, более того, "ослепительно(-)яркий" — не всегда о цвете, а чаще о свете (как в упомянутом сочинении).

Comment: _М_Г: Думаю, правило о дефисном написании оттенков цветов здесь неприменимо_. === В ПАС это правило сформулировано так: _§ 129. Следующие разряды прилагательных пишутся через дефис. <…> 2. Прилагательные, обозначающие **оттенки качества** (преимущественно цвета или вкуса), напр.: <…> **кричаще-яркий**._ См. http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=70#pp70

Comment: Если "кричаще-" можно рассматривать как атрибут качества внешнего объекта, то "ослепительно" - скорее, субъективное восприятие степени проявления качества.(как и в случае "удивительно яркий").  В восприятии наблюдателя яркость чего-то слепила его, но едва ли яркость могла бы "кричать" наблюдателю или напр. "убивать" его ("убойно-яркий" - оба элемента относятся к самому качеству).

Answer (score 4):

**По правилам надо писать через дефис: ослепительно-яркий.**

Правила такие:

1) **Справочник под ред. Лопатина** "Слитно, раздельно или через дефис?" (2012 год).

2. **ПАС:** http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=70#pp70

   Прилагательные, обозначающие оттенки качества (**преимущественно цвета или вкуса**), напр.: бледно-жёлтый, густо-синий, светло-голубой, тёмно-русый и др.

Это правило **распространяется и на любые индивидуально-авторские образования,** обозначающие сочетания признаков. Такие сложные прилагательные широко употребляются в художественной и публицистической речи, напр.: тяжело-звонкое скаканье (П.).

**3. Розенталь** http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=49#pp49

11. Пишутся через дефис сложные прилагательные, обозначающие оттенки цветов:бледно-голубой...
12. Следует различать сложные прилагательные (со слитным или дефисным написанием) и словосочетания, состоящие из наречия на -о/-е и прилагательного или причастия: ослепительно голубой...

**Возможно различное написание** одних и тех же определений в зависимости от их понимания: искусственно-напыщенная поза ("искусственная и напыщенная’) — искусственно напыщенная поза (‘искусственно созданная напыщенность’).

Чем ближе по значению элементы сочетания основ, **чем они синонимичнее,** тем заметнее выражается в них признак с добавочным оттенком, что дает основание для употребления сложного прилагательного **с дефисным написанием:** грубо-отталкивающий вид.

**ОСЛЕПИТЕЛЬНЫЙ**,  1. **Очень яркий,** слепящий глаза. О. снег. О-ое солнце. О. фейерверк. О. блеск. **ЯРКИЙ,** - 1. Очень сильный, сияющий, **ослепительный**; излучающий сильный свет. Я. свет. Я-ая лампа. Я-ое солнце.

Прилгательные являются близкими синонимами с градацией признака, поэтому **даже по Розенталю надо использовать дефисное написание.**

Пример с однородными прилагательными: **Яркий, ослепительный** свет ударил Михаилу в глаза [Федор Абрамов. Дом (1973-1978)]

Comment: А почему нет? По крайней мере за дефисное написание "серо-буро-малиновый"  я ручаюсь.

Answer (score 3):

Меня *улыбнуло* прозвучавшее в одном из ответов в этой теме утверждение:

> Прилагательные [*ослепительный* и *яркий*] являются близкими
>   синонимами с градацией признака, поэтому **даже по Розенталю надо
>   использовать дефисное написание.**

Розенталь с нашим форумом не был знаком и потому рекомендовал в своих справочниках не дефисное, а раздельное написание: ***ослепительно яркий***.

См. *Розенталь Д.Э., Теленкова М.А. "Словарь трудностей русского языка", изд. 5-е, М., 1986:*

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Раздельного написания для ***ослепительно яркий*** придерживались и Букчина Б.З. с Калакуцкой   Л.П. (*"Сложные слова", М., 1974*). Такое написание было ими сохранено и в вышедшем тридцать лет спустя словаре *"Слитно или раздельно?"* (4-е изд., М., 2006):

Дефисное написание ***ослепительно-яркий***, насколько мне известно, стало фиксироваться другими словарями лишь после появления такого его написания в *"Русском орфографическом словаре"* (Лопатин В.В. и др.).

По-моему, это было 4-е издании (М., 2011), но не уверен. Во всяком случае, в первом издании этого словаря (М., 1999) ***ослепительно/яркий*** не фиксировалось ни в каком написании.

Приняли дефисное написание ***ослепительно-яркий*** и Букчина с Калакуцкой. В предисловию к их словарю *"Слитно? Раздельно? Через дефис?"* (М., 2017) говорится:

> Надо сказать, что проблема написания сложных слов стоит перед пишущими
>   читателями уже несколько десятилетий.
>
> Решение ее упирается в несовершенство "Правил русской орфографии и
>   пунктуации" 1956 года… Нечеткость формулировок правил вызвала разнобой
>   в написании в разных словарях и даже в разных изданиях
>   "Орфографического словаря русского языка" Института русского языка
>   имени В.В. Виноградова РАН.
>
> Ситуация значительно улучшилась с выходом в 2005 году "Русского
>   орфографического словаря", изданного Институтом русского языка имени
>   В.В. Виноградова РАН (ответственный редактор доктор филол. наук В.В.
>   Лопатин)… Это нормативный орфографический справочник. Именно на его
>   норму, зафиксированную также и в последнем (2011 г.) издании, и
>   опирается наш словарь.

Из этого словаря Букчиной с Калакуцкой:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Таким образом, на сегодняшний день нормативным является дефисное написание сложного прилагательного ***ослепительно-яркий***.

Comment: А меня улыбнуло то, что статистика словарей у нас  всегда первом месте (кто, когда и как писал), а смысл написаний всегда на последнем.  В то же время критерий  (для всех сложных прилагательных) один и тот же: если яркий, ослепительный, то дефисное написание (это два прилагательных). Если яркий до ослепительности (это наречие и прилагательное). Но понятия эти настолько близки по значению, что использовать две разные формы нет смысла, только путаницу создавать. .

Comment: Поэтому уже  2005 году в справочнике Розенталя остался только ослепительно голубой, а ослепительно яркий отсутствует.  И еще есть разница: по Розенталю и у Розенталя (его годы жизни 1900 - 1994).  А вот в 1956 году ВСЕ оттенки цветов предлагалось писать через дефис, к тому и возвращаемся.  Разные формы нужны там, где это действительно меняет смысл, а искать разницу в яркости до ослепительности - только время терять

Comment: Хорошая иллюстрация истории администрирования в языке. Осталось дождаться, что будет объявлено нормой после выхода у рановцев словаря под редакцией следующего начальника :)

Answer (score 2):

[**ослепительный**](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?bts=x&word=%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9&help=1)

**1.** Очень яркий, слепящий глаза.
О. снег. О-ое солнце. О. фейерверк. О. блеск.
// Необычайно чистый, свежий.
О-ая свежесть листвы. О-ые по своей белизне манжеты. О-ая чистота в доме.

**2.** Производящий сильное впечатление, поражающий (красотой, блеском и т. п.).
О-ая красота. О-ое убранство. О. пейзаж. О-ая улыбка.
<Ослепительно, О. блестит море. **Ослепительно белый снег.** О. чистое бельё.

Ослепительными мы называем очень яркий свет, блеск, сияние и т. п., а также то, что их излучает или отражает:

Ослепительный свет заливал комнату.
Ослепительный диск Солнца сиял на небе.
Он поднял голову и увидел ослепительные купола церкви.

Получается, что ослепительно яркий (= очень ярко яркий) – это плеоназм, требующий осторожного, "выборочного" употребления.

Вот примеры с дефисным написанием (их совсем немного):

*Все ехали молча, как вдруг кто-то заметил вдали [**ослепительно-яркий**](http://belwolf.com/blog/vladimir-episkoposyan.html) свет. Казалось, на горизонте пылало холодное пламя, по своей силе спорящее с лучами солнца.*

*Весь остров излучает ослепительно-яркий свет — и мы подумали, что именно так светятся драгоценности с нежным жемчугом...*

Но, если бы мне пришлось использовать это словосочетание, я бы его написала все-таки раздельно. Ни одно из правил — ни о дефисном написании оттенков цветов, ни о прилагательных, обозначающих оттенки качества (преимущественно цвета или вкуса), — здесь "не работает".

Comment: Вы не считаете выражение "ослепительно яркий" плеоназмом? Я вижу здесь отличие от "ослепительно белого", "обжигающе горячего" и т.п.

Comment: Здесь не может быть плеоназма: яркость как свойство излучающей поверхности объективно измеряема; ослепительность - субъективная, оценочная категория, отделённая от свойства. Пример словаря (Большой универсальный словарь русского языка, И. С. Иванов, Центрполиграф, 2011, 927 с.), где есть рядом **ослепительно белый**, **ослепительно яркий** и **ослепляюще-белый** (с объектом отглагольной формой связана способность "ослеплять"):

https://books.google.ru/books/content?id=CavOAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA352&img=1&zoom=3&hl=en&ots=hDx1fbplqq&sig=ACfU3U1uQmI-4UBuoS-QXAA2kqsykfBcgg&w=1280

Comment: @Alex_ander Вопрос ведь был не о тавтологии или плеоназме. Я выразила _свою_ точку зрения: мне так _показалось_ (я ведь не филолог). Спасибо за пример из "Большого словаря" - о раздельном написании - значит, в этом-то я не ошиблась.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Я не обратил внимания на упоминание этого аспекта в вашем ответе и просто отреагировал на комментарий. В целом я с ответом согласен и "плюсанул" его по поводу раздельного написания :)

Comment: Спасибо. Ваше мнение для меня особо ценно.

Answer (score 0):

В словаре Слитно или раздельно? Орфографический словарь-справочник. — М.: Русский язык. Б. З. Букчина, Л. П. Какалуцкая. 1998, зафиксировано дефисное написание.

Это словосочетание подпадает под следующее правило.

Пишутся через дефис сложные прилагательные, обозначающие оттенки цветов:

бледно-голубой

тускло-серый

чёрно-бурый

блёкло-розовый

ярко-красный и др.

**См.: Розенталь Д. Э. Справочник по русскому языку: орфография и пунктуация.**

Comment: Думаю, Вы ошибаетесь. Ослепительность — не оттенок цвета. Более того, "ослепительно-яркий" — это в сочинении сказано не о цвете, а о свете.

Comment: А разве ослепительно-яркий цвет не бывает? К тому же, это словосочетание зафиксировано и в орфографическом словаре под редакцией Лопатина.Там тоже через дефис.

Comment: А ссылку на словарь можно получить?

Comment: https://orthography.academic.ru/21850/%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE

Comment: Спасибо, я включил это в текст вопроса.

Comment: Словари расходятся и насчёт обжигающе горячего. Я лично не вижу грамматической разницы между удивительно ярким и ослепительно ярким (цветом или светом - всё равно): первая часть сочетания - о субъективном восприятии объективно характеризуемого качества.